# how to get data in firestore by specific user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

The logged in user can also see the activities of other users. but I only want the logged in user's activities to be seen. Do I need to make changes in the query section?

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    const q = query(collection(db,'etkinlik'));
    const unsub = onSnapshot(q,(snap)=>{
      const array = snap.docs.map(doc=>{
        return{
          id : doc.id,
          title : doc.get('title'),
          start: doc.get('start').toDate(),
          allDay : doc.get('allDay')

        }
      });
      setData([...array]);
    })
    return ()=>{unsub()}
  })  
 const handleDateClick = (args) => {
    if(args.jsEvent.altKey) {
      const title= prompt('Enter Title',args.dateStr);
      const event = {
        title: title ? title : args.dateStr,
        start: args.date,
        allDay: true,
        uid: uid,
        owner: user.uid
      }
      addDoc(collection(db,'etkinlik'),event)
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to get data in firestore by specific user?

You're looking for [query operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators) with `where`, like this:

```js
query(collection(db,'etkinlik'), where('uid', '==', uid));
```

This will query only for documents that fulfill the `where` condition. However, this doesn't stop other users from query the data.

> I only want the logged in user's activities to be seen

Lock the collection down with [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started). For example, to make a collection named `etkinlik` only readable for clients with a matching `uid`:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /etkinlik {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming that documents in `etkinlik` have a field `uid` (as indicated in your source code example; but you also have `owner` there, so it depends on you how you use those fields).

[See docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#deploying_rules), to deploy the Security Rules. It's a good idea to use the Firebase Console and test the rules in the Playground section.

Comment: when i changed permissions like this i got a problem like "Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions."

Comment: Then that's exactly that. You have insufficient permissions for the path you've specified in the snapshot listener. Every path and every operation that is not specified in your Security Rules is forbidden by default - for the rule above, you allow only read operations for `etkinlik` collection; nothing else. That might be the issue for you. Test it out in the Playground in Firebase Console, that's what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict a user from seeing certain data (such as other user's data), you will need to develop database rules. Restricting one user from seeing data can also be done locally, but for security reasons you should develop this from the backend.

Security rule instructions for [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and [Realtime Datase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) depending on what you're using.

Comment: `rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 4, 24);
    }
  }
}`Here is the settings part. how do i update here